# Testing yeoman sub-generator

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to test a generator using the `inDir()` helper method to run 2 different test scenarios in 2 different directories, and getting confusing results.

The first time the generator is run, everything works as expected. It copies all of the files into my `tmp1` directory.

When the generator is run from the second `describe` block, however, the only files copied are `.yo-rc` and `Gruntfile.js`.

I think this has something to do with my test setup, because if I put a `.skip` on the first `describe`, then the generator runs correctly in `tmp2/`.

In the following example, I've used the same configuration for both to reduce the number of variables, but in practice, each generator would be passed a different set of prompts.

Here's my test file:

```
let prompts = require('../fixtures/prompts.js');

describe('generator,', function () {
  this.timeout(0);

  let generator = require.resolve('../../app/index.js');

  beforeEach(function() {
    let options = {
      skipInstall: true,
    }

    this.generator = helpers.run(require.resolve('../../app/index.js'))
      .withPrompts(prompts.default)
      .withOptions(options)
  });

  describe('in tmp1/', function() {

    beforeEach(function(done) {

      this.generator
        .inDir(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../tmp1'))
        .on('end', done);
    });

    it('should copy the files', function(){
      assert.file('dummyfile.txt');
    });
  });

  describe('in tmp2/', function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
      this.generator
        .inDir(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../tmp2'))
        .on('end', done);
    });

    it('should not be crazy', function() {
      assert.file('dummyfile.txt');
    }); 
  });
});
```

What might be causing this?

**Note:**

For context, I want to test the scenario of running a sub-generator in a folder that already contains a project created by the base generator, to make sure that it correctly uses the existing project configs. I'm not sure if what I'm doing here is the best way to accomplish that, but I thought this problem might be confusing enough to merit its own question.

Answer (score 1):

`inDir()` cleans the directory.

If you need to some to exists in order to run your second generator, then you can use the callback parameter of `inDir` to create dummy files and make your assertions against.

Comment: That's what I'm ultimately trying to do here: copy the files from `tmp1` into `tmp2` using `inDir()`. However, when I run the generator from the second `describe` block, even if I am not copying files, it does not run correctly. In the example, both calls to helpers.run() are identical, apart from the target directory, but they do not produce identical results. I'm concerned that my tests are not independent of each other, but I can't figure out why.